# Bash Script to Check if Given IP is Valid A Record for Host

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need to use cron and bash to check if IP 111.222.333.444 is still valid for host sub.domain.com.

I have tried *grep* with -Pzo, but it didn't work. I don't want to install *pcregrep*.

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddressused=$1

#Run a dig for sub.domain.com:

ipaddresscurrent='dig +short sub.domain.com'

echo "$ipaddresscurrent" | grep -Pzo "$ipaddressused" && echo "found" && exit 0 || echo "not found" && exit 1
```

*ipaddresscurrent* returns multiple IPs, one per line.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this be enough?

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddressused=$1

if grep -q -P "$ipaddressused" < <(dig +short sub.domain.com); then
    echo "found"
    exit 0
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

What was wrong with your script?

- The line

  ```
  ipaddresscurrent='dig +short sub.domain.com'
  ```

  assigns the string `dig +short sub.domain.com` to the variable `ipaddresscurrent`. You probably, instead, wanted to assign to the variable `ipaddresscurrent` the *output* of the *command* `dig +short sub.domain.com`. This is done either using the old and deprecated backticks:

  ```
  ipaddresscurrent=`dig +short sub.domain.com`
  ```

  (but please don't ever use backticks!) or the more modern, robust and nestable `$(...)` as:

  ```
  ipaddresscurrent=$(dig +short sub.domain.com)
  ```
- `grep -Pzo` doesn't really do what you're expecting. Instead you want to run `grep` *quiently* (hence the `-q` flag) and check its output, so the following would have been valid:

  ```
  echo "$ipaddresscurrent" | grep -q -P "$ipaddressused" && echo "found" && exit 0 || echo "not found" && exit 1
  ```

Since you don't really need the variable `ipaddresscurrent`, I prefered to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to feed `grep`.

Also, don't use long chains of `&& || &&`'s, it's hard to read, and can have some subtle side effects.

If you want to stick with your variable, you need a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) as so:

```
#!/bin/bash

ipaddressused=$1
ipaddresscurrent=$(dig +short sub.domain.com)

if grep -q -P "$ipaddressused" <<< "$ipaddresscurrent"; then
    echo "found"
    exit 0
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

As you note in your comment:

> should be noted that if the $ipaddressused supplied is 111.222.333.4 and 111.222.333.456 is present on the list a match will also occur. this could cause problems.

I actually didn't really know if this was a requested feature or not (since the argument of the script is a regex, that's actually why I left the `-P` flag). If you really want to exactly match an IP, here's how you could proceed:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -q "^${1//./\.}$" < <(dig +short sub.domain.com); then
    echo "found"
    exit 0
else
    echo "not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

assuming that `dig` used this way will output only one ip per line.

Comment: thanks! if you don't mind explaining why that works and the previous one didnt I would appreciate it.

Comment: should be noted that if the $ipaddressused supplied is 111.222.333.4 and 111.222.333.456 is a valid result in dig, a match will also occur. this could cause problems.